# JSP how to concat value in name attribute?

Tags: java, jsp

Here is what I use in Thymeleaf. I just concat dishIdQuantityMap with dish.id.

```
        <div class="single-menu" th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
                              <input
                            th:value="0"
                            th:name="${'dishIdQuantityMap[' + dish.id + ']'}"
                            type="number"
                            min="0"
                            max="100"
                            step="1"
                            readonly
                    />
```

And it works fine, but if I do the same in JSP

```
   <input
                                value="0"
                                name="${'dishIdQuantityMap[' + dish.id + ']' }"
                                type="number"
                                min="0"
                                max="100"
                                step="1"
                                readonly
                        />
```

It fails. Exception happens on line 142
[image]
What do I do wrong?

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
> "dishIdQuantityMap"

UPD.
If I do it like this, it kinda works

```
name="${'dishIdQuantityMap['}${dish.id}${']'}"
```

Comment: Most likely you need to wrap the input in `foreach`. `jsp` doesn't know anything about `dish.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too many quotes. Here is a demonstration JSP.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap, java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    pageContext.setAttribute("list", list);
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("a", 11);
    map.put("b", 22);
    map.put("c", 33);
    pageContext.setAttribute("map", map);
%>
<c:forEach items="${map}" varStatus="loopCount">
    ${map[list[loopCount.index]]}
</c:forEach>
```

The output is
11 22 33 .
You could try using   name="${dishIdQuantityMap[dish.id]}"
As Jeka_FRIZZ pointed out dish must be in scope.